# efficient way of making a library for different languages and platforms

Tags: javascript, python, c++

Hello i need to write 4 libraries in 3 different languages for 2 platforms  for my PCB module to work on the raspberry pi and arduino. Most of the library just contain functions of bit manipulation which will then be passed to a function that will be unique to each language and platform combination.

So basically the 4 libraries will be 90-95% identical. Now i find it very inefficient that i will have to code for all 4 libraries, where all i do is just adjust the syntaxes. This can also be a pain when there is an update that has to be done on the library because you have to update all 4 of them. There has to be a better way of doing this

[image]

My idea is to have a core library where it will be written in one language that can be loaded by a some sort of *Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL)* written using the three different languages it is needed python, javascript, and c++. My problem is what will that language be. And what will i use to load it into the other languages. Would C be my best option?

[image]

Comment: What are you running the JavaScript in?

Comment: @AlanBirtles its for a NodeJS module. The raspberry pi supports node.JS

Comment: As far as I know, python can use [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to load a C library and javascript can use [`wasm`](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/emscripting-a-c-library). There might be other alternatives out there but this is what I found.

Comment: I'd personally write the core part in C++ and make a python [extension](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) to use it. Just note that functions that will be called by the Python interpreter (in particular, module initialization functions) have to be declared using `extern "C"`. You might be able to do it similarly for javascript. There's no need for a HAL for C++ if you do it like that.

Comment: @Ruks are ctypes and wasm native libraries for python and javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the simplest option would be to write your library in C++ and to add bindings for that library. That way you will have your "master" library and also you will be able to use the library in other languages. Proposed diagram would look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I'd expect the Core C++ library to be available for direct use on the Raspberry platform too though.

Comment: I have to use some hardware specific libraries that are raspberry pi / arduino specific so there still will be some sort of layer, but yes its definitely much easier since it uses the same c/c++ language. the tricky bit is python and js

Comment: Can you elaborate more by what you mean by bindings sir, i seem to be getting a different result searching it in google.

Comment: @Jakequin Bindings are basically a glue to expose an API written in one language to another language. Boost.Python, for instance, is a library that helps to expose C++ code to Python (or vice versa). You compile your code in C++ and then from Python you can simply do "import mylib" and work in Python as usual.